# How a job queueing software works

Tags: worker, job-queue

I have a small website where and i am allowing people to  sign up for accounts.I want after someone has signed up,he/she is sent a welcome email and a confirmation email.I want to attempt to do this using a job queuing system.

I have never used a job queuing system before but this is what i want to do.

I want to have some jobs to have priority over others.For instance,if someone is from my area code,i want the confirmation email to be sent asap or immediately while if a user is from abroad,i want to send the conformation email after some minutes,say five.

My question is on how the actual jobs are processed.Can  workers be made to process some jobs immediately if a job has priority over others and some other workers wait five minutes or more before the job is started.

Second question,how do job queuing system know there are some jobs in the queue?. Does the queuing system poll the queue after every set time,i.e 5 minutes or is there some mechanism that keep it notified of new arrived jobs?.